# ionic build ios fails after using development push notification error code 65 for command

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework

Hello guys i was working on a Ionic guide to test push notification for dev. after following the tutorial on 
http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-quick-start
i tried to push notification and it does show up in the browser with kind of alert. After that i tried to build for ios. Is this error because it is under development? or it requires full push for ios setup ? like adding the certificates and all... If you guys know please guide me. Thank You.

Here is the error

** BUILD FAILED **

> **The following build commands failed**:
>       CompileC build/example.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainViewController.o example/Classes/MainViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>   ERROR building one of the platforms:
>   **Error code 65 for command**: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,example.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,example,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error:
>   **Error code 65 for command**: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,example.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,example,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/wangeltamang/Documents/est_ionic/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: This error code has something to do witht the phonegap push plugin

Comment: if there is the hello cordova.xcode project and the folder then it will work

Comment: that's the conclusion i came to